# If I reject a postdoc job offer, should I tell them where I will finally go for postdoc?

Tags: postdocs, job, rejection

If I reject a postdoc offer, should I inform the PI where I declined the offer about the institution and PI I will eventually work with? Academia is a very small world, and there's a good chance we will cross paths in the future. Would letting the PI I initially declined know where I'll be working now demonstrate my honesty, or could it potentially have negative effects? Is this considered professional behavior?

Comment: "Would letting the PI I initially declined know where I'll be working now demonstrate my honesty" I don't see how honesty enters into the picture at all. In what way would it be "dishonest" if you don't tell the PI which offer you decided to accept instead? In what way does it demonstrate your honesty if you do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would simply thank them for the offer and say you have accepted another offer elsewhere. There is no need to say where.

If you have a personal relationship with people at the institution you are declining, I'd suggest the opposite. But not in the more common case.

There is nothing "wrong" in any sense about turning down an offer. People will understand that you have a better option for whatever reasons are important to you.

And, if your field is small, there is no reason to reject future contact or collaboration with the institution you have turned down.

But, either way you play it, I don't see negative consequences as long as you say thanks.

Comment: To "if personal relationship", I might also add "if they ask you"—that shows genuine curiosity about the applicant's career, which is worth engaging with.

Answer (score 2):

A good approach is to email or call them and politely inform about your decision to maintain working relationships. That should be enough.

Comment: I agree with this. You always want to expand your network and increase the number of people who want to work with you. I would email them and say, "Despite the attractiveness of your offer. I have decided to accept a position with XYZ. I very much like the work you and your group are doing, and hope we find opportunities to collaborate together in the future "